# Scrollviewer around itemstemplate picking up wrong itemstemplate

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, itemscontrol

I need a scrollviewer around an ItemsControl whose ItemsPaneltemplate depends upon a property IsClusterSupported. 
Without ScrollViewer, ItemsControl always displays the correct ItemsPanel, but when I added scrollviewer code, ClusterMapItemsPanelTemplate is shown even if IsClusterSupported=False.

What could be happening wrong here? I have attached the code below.

```
<Grid Name="MapGrid">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsScrollingSupported}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ScrollViewer.Style>
        <ItemsControl Name="ItemsControlInnerMap" Loaded="ItemsControlInnerMap_Loaded"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCol}" Tag="{Binding IsClusterSupported, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}">
            <ItemsControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource MapItemsPanelTemplate}"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsClusterSupported}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource ClusterMapItemsPanelTemplate}"/>
                            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ClusterMapGridContainerStyle}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.Style>

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <Border>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LabelTxt}"/>
                  </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle x:Name="MyGroup">

                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Border Name="BD" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
                                            <ItemsPresenter Name="ClusterPresenter" Tag="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        </Border>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource BorderVisibilityConvertor}}" Value="false">
                                                <Setter TargetName="BD" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <!--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863271/wpf-using-grid-as-itemshost-stacking-multiple-items-in-single-cell-automatical-->
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Items[0].ClusterGridRow}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Items[0].ClusterGridColumn}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>

                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Grid Name="ClusterMapGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  Loaded="ClusterMapGrid_Loaded"
                                  MaxHeight="{Binding AllowedMaxHeight}" MaxWidth="{Binding AllowedMaxWidth}"
                                  MinHeight="{Binding ReqMinHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ReqMinWidth}">
                            </Grid>ReqMinHeight
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>

                </GroupStyle>
            </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

RDV(01/04/2016):I found something interesting here, hopefully getting closer to solution but still need help.

1. All my bindings are working fine; I debugged with & without scrollviewer and saw correct ItemsPanel in ItemsControl. ItemsControl's IsGrouping property is also set correctly.
2. When I have a scrollviewer around ItemsControl, ClusterMapGrid (the GroupStyle.Panel) gets loaded irrespective I have a cluster or not. Once this is loaded, non-cluster template (MapsItemsPanelTemplate) is not loaded.
3. To get past this issue, I tried binding ClusterMapGrid Visibility to ItemsControl's IsGrouping property, but again somehow ClusterMapGrid is loaded in case of scrollviewer and once it is loaded non-cluster template fails to load.
4. I used snoop to check the ClusterMapGrid's Visibility, I could see that it is collapsed, but if manually change it in snoop to any other value, non-cluster template loads and everything works fine. I tried setting the visibility to collapsed in ClusterMapGrid_Loaded event, but it did not help either.
5. Further debugging I found that ScrollViewer is loading all items within it- hence ClusterMapGrid is loaded, once I change the visibility using Snoop, it is unloaded in case of non-cluster scenario.

Problem Statement: How to unload ClusterMapGrid once it is loaded and I know this is a non-cluster scenario.

Comment: Will setting the `DataContext` explicitly on `ItemsControl` work? `<ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}}" ... >`

Comment: Also, look in the `Output` window for any binding/application errors and update the question to tell us what they are, if any.

Comment: I verified (using snoop & attaching a debugger) that ItemsControl's Tag property is set correctly based on IsClusterSupported value. For some reason, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High is not working.

Comment: are you running in Debug or Release configuration when testing?  Do you notice a difference of PresentationTraceSources depending on the build configuration?

Comment: And you might be wanting to bind the items panel data trigger to `ItemsControlInnerMap.Tag`, not `IsClusterSupported`?

Comment: I am running in Debug mode; PresentationTraceSources used to work, but its not working now- I am working to fix it. I had Trigger instead of Datatrigger which was bound to ItemsControlInnerMap.Tag but it didnt work hence I used DataTrigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem  is that ScrollViewer initializes & loads everything in XAML even if it is not meant to be loaded (for e.g., GroupStyle.Panel should be loaded if IsGrouping on ItemsControl is true, but with scrollviewer, it is getting loaded anyways).

**Solution**: Comment out GroupStyle.Panel from XAML and add it as ItemsPanelTemplate in Resources:

```
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ClusterPanelTemplate">
                <Grid Name="ClusterMapGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"                                                                      
                      Loaded="ClusterMapGrid_Loaded"
                      MaxHeight="{Binding AllowedMaxHeight}" MaxWidth="{Binding AllowedMaxWidth}"
                      MinHeight="{Binding ReqMinHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ReqMinWidth}"/>
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Add the following in ItemsControlInnerMap_Loaded event code-behind:

```
private void ItemsControlInnerMap_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((sender as ItemsControl).IsGrouping)
            {
                (sender as ItemsControl).GroupStyle[0].Panel = (ItemsPanelTemplate)this.FindResource("ClusterPanelTemplate");
            }
            else
            {
                (sender as ItemsControl).GroupStyle.Clear();
            }
        }
```